# Keymap that is dependent on the buffer

Tags: key-bindings, commands, shell-mode

I want to create a "toggle shell" shortcut with F1 such that it will run `shell` when I'm in any other buffer, but will call `mode-line-other-buffer` when I'm in the shell buffer. What is an efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You set `shell-command` as global key-binding for <kbd>F1</kbd>
and you add a hook function to `shell-mode-hook` that sets the local key binding to `mode-line-other-buffer`.

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "<f1>") #'shell)

(defun my-shell-mode-hook ()
  "My preferred settings for `shell-mode'."
  (local-set-key (kbd "<f1>") #'mode-line-other-buffer))

(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook #'my-shell-mode-hook)
```

You can put this stuff into your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

Comment: Thanks, this works beautifully. Perhaps I should do my homework and actually learn Elisp in my free time.

Comment: That's the wonder of Emacs. You can start small with little scripts and then graduate to writing your own modes or even contributing to Emacs. There's no barrier to entry.